# Adding List<T> to a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know what would be the best approach for this problem that I have.

I have an object **Study**, where in each **Studies** can have a multiple **Tanks** assigned to it. Then on each **Tank** assigned to that **study** contains **Logs**. I'm thinking that I could get it, by getting the List of tanks assigned to that study then loop from each element of list tank to get the list of logs for every tank.

If I'm returning `List<Logs>` to get the Logs of each Tank assigned to this study, how can I return `List<logs>` from `List<Tank>` that is assigned to Study?

```
//Study Class

    public class Study{
          public Guid StudyId;
          public String StudyName;
          public List<Tanks> AssignedTanks;
    }

//Tanks Class
    public class Tanks{
            public Guid TankId;
            public String TankName;
    }

//Logs Class
public class Logs{
        public Guid LogId;
        public Guid StudyId;
        public Guid TankId;
        public DateTime LogDate;
        public double Log;
}
```

I've created also a ViewModel to hold the list of Logs for each Tank that is assigned to the study.

```
//ListOfLogs
public class ListOfLogs{
        public List<Logs> ListLogs;
}
```

And a  method to get all assigned tanks in the study, then iterate the result to get the logs of each tanks that is assigned to that study.

```
public static List<ListOfLogs> GetLogs(Guid StudyId) {
    var StudyLogs = new List<ListOfLogs>;
    
    var AssignedTanks = new List<Tanks>();
    
    //Get the assigned tanks for the study
    AssigendTanks = Study.GetTank(StudyID);
    
    Guid _TankId;
    //Loop to get the logs of each tanks
    For(int i = 0; i < AssignedTanks.Count; i++) {
            var GetLogs = new List<Logs>;

            _TankId = AssignedTanks[i].TankId;

            //Get the Logs of each tanks;
            GetLogs = Logs.GetLogs(StudyId, _TankId);

            //Add List<Logs> to List<ListOfLogs>
            StudyLogs.add(GetLogs);
    }

    return StudyLogs;
 }
```

I'm having an error in `StudyLogs.add(GetLogs);` cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

I don't know if its the best approach though.

The result should return List of all Logs that can be sorted out by Tanks.

Comment: To make your question easier to understand, please show the classes.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've added the classes now.

Answer (score 1):

If get it right, one way to get all Logs from all Tanks in a study, is to do this:

```
var allLogs = new List<Log>;
Study.Tanks.ForEach(tank => allLogs.AddRange(tank.Logs));
```

Now, you can return `allLogs` from a method, property, or however you are comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Study> studies;

List<Log> logs = studies
    .SelectMany(s => s.Tanks.SelectMany(t => t.Logs))
    .ToList();
```

`SelectMany` flattens a nested collection.

Comment: Sorry for not so clear question. I've added class for a clearer question. If SelectMany flattens a nested collection, can i get only the result for example the logs of Tank 1?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your relations, add studyid to class Tank, and remove it from class logs. Or add list of logs to study class and access it like a property, if you consider the log class consider study and tank independent.